# Stringifying openGL enums

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

So there has been a lot of times where I needed to know what the enums returned by certain opengl operations are, to print them on the terminal to see what's going on.

It doesn't seem there's any kind of function available for stringifying the enums at the moment, so I'm thinking of going straight to gl.h (actually I'm gonna use libglew's header for now), grabbing the #defines and creating a huge switch table for convenience purposes.

Is there any better way, and how would you deal with having to port things to OpenGL ES?

Comment: You'll probably meet some problems, as different enum names may have the same hexadecimal values in OpenGL (especially if you consider the extensions - a switch will refuse to compile because of ambiguities.

Comment: oh, nice catch. I was just finishing up the thing too.. gonna compile and see how many of those duplicates there are.

Comment: Okay, found out there's like 10 duplicate case value compilation error. You'd think they'd at least keep track of the values and not clump GL_NEVER with GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT..

Comment: Their point of view (I suppose) is that GL_NEVER and GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT cannot be used by the same gl command, so the enum values may alias. It's no problem for OpenGL, only for helping tools.

Comment: Some GL defines are bitsets, meant to be bitwise-or'd with each other. If there is more than one set of those (I assume yes), then there's no reasonable way of preventing aliasing.

Comment: By the way, if you're on non-ES OpenGL and want to print the values, maybe you'd be better of using a GL debugger like GLintercept instead?

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense (bitsets). Actually, I'm using gDEBugger now. It's pretty good. I just wanted a way for asserts to be able to print and send back openGL state data on error reports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gluErrorString` is the function you're looking for in OpenGL, as GLU library is normally always available alongside with GL.

I don't have experience in OpenGL ES, but Google turned up [GLUes](http://code.google.com/p/glues/) that may help you.

Comment: But does gluErrorString take into account all the other GL enums? for example, glGet return values?

Comment: Oops, indeed, I see your point ; it's getting late here... gluErrorString is probably too limited for your needs, sorry.

Comment: Deprecated (on MacOSX at least)

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL has some official .spec files that define the API, there is one enum.spec that lists all the enum names and their values. You just need to write a simple program to parse the file and produce a lookup mapping.

The file can be found at http://www.opengl.org/registry/ (specifically http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/enum.spec)

Manually processing gl.h would work but the spec files are updated for new versions and if you have a program to generate the code for you then you don't have to do anything to get the new enums in. Also gl.h file is implementation specific. So it might change between nVidia, ATI, and on different platforms.

Comment: These links are dead now, how did you navigate to them on the site? There seems to be a lot of heavy technical documentation there

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenGL Registry](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php) contains comprehensive information on the OpenGL API. Notably [the gl.xml file in the XML API registry](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/xml/gl.xml) lists all enums, including their names and values. Creating a lookup table from that data should be simple enough.